# Defining SQLAlchemy enum column length

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to know if it is possible to define with SQLAlchemy the length of an enum type field. In my case the classes are defined as follows:

**EnumTest.py**

```
from enum import Enum


class EnumTest(str, Enum):
    EnumTest1 = "EnumTest1"
    EnumTest2 = "EnumTest2"
    EnumTest3 = "EnumTest3"
```

**TestTable.py**

```
from models import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, String

from .EnumTest import EnumTest


class TestTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = "test"

    id = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    my_enum = Column(Enum(EnumTest), nullable=False)
```

My goal is to create a field called **my_enum** of type **character varying** of length **50** as in the case of the id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) say

> The Enum type will make use of the backend’s native “ENUM” type if one
> is available; otherwise, it uses a VARCHAR datatype
>
> ...
>
> length – allows specifying a custom length for the VARCHAR when
> Enum.native_enum is False. By default it uses the length of the
> longest value.

So, you can set `native_enum=False` and `length=50`. It might look like this

```
my_enum = Column(Enum(EnumTest, native_enum=False, length=50), nullable=False)
```